# Not taking the Else-if input powershell with Switch statement

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, powershell-5.0

I need help with PowerShell code. I have to update a couple of programs using PowerShell, but I am getting errors while running the script.

Inputs to the code are 1 and 0 for Switch condition and other inputs are foo, boo, Oracle to be updated, based on condition software will be updated.

```powershell
$param = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the input 1 or 0"
[bool]$upg = $true
$sftp = Read-Host "Please Enter the softwre to update"
switch ($param)
{
    0{
        Write-Output "Today is monday"
    }
    1
    {
        $prm_prd = Read-Host -Prompt "Are you going for operation upgrade"
        if ($prm_prd -eq $upg)
        {
            Write-Output "System upgrade"

            if ($sftp -eq 'foo')
            {
                Write-Output "foo upgrade"
            }
            elseif ( $sftp -eq 'boo')
            {
                Write-output "boo upgrade"
            }
            elseif ( $sftp -eq 'Oracle')
            {
                Write-output "oracle upgrade"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you post some form of this before?  Elseif not else-if.

Comment: Hi @js2010 i still did not get the solution, how dows switch statement work for else-if statement , it is kind of weird , why it is not entering the else-if condition

Comment: `elseif`.  There is no dash `-`